# Storing & recovering 2-dimensional Array in a Class

Tags: arrays, vb.net, multidimensional-array

I just recently moved from VB6 to VB.NET and I'm recoding an old app. So I'm pretty unexperienced with .NET so far.

I have multiple (lets say 4 in this code example) twodimensional string arrays (or actually an array of arrays) which I want to store as a ComboBox items ie. one twodimensional array is one item.

```
Public Class MyItem

    Private sName As String
    Private sArr As Array()

    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ParamArray Arr As Array())
        sName = Name
        sArr = Arr
    End Sub

    Public Property Arr() As Array()
        Get
            Return sArr
        End Get

        Set(ByVal sValue As Array())
            sArr = sValue
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return sName
    End Function

End Class

---

Dim sMyArray as Array()

For i As Integer = 0 to 3
    sMyArray = Nothing   ' resetting the array before refilling it
    '
    ' No code here but filling sMyArray by reading a text file, each line
    ' number as dim 1 and splitted each line into dim 2 with ";" using Split(sRead, ";")
    ' so Debub.Print(sMyArray(0)(0)) prints the beginning of the first line until first ";" <- this works fine
    '
    ' Then passing sMyArray to a ComboBox item
    ' 
    ComboBox.Items.Add(New MyItem("item" & i, sMyArray))
Next i
```

The problem is that when recovering the arrays from ComboCox items **only the last ComboBox item has array data**. So for example

```
Dim sMyNewArray As Array() = ComboBox.Items.Item(0).Arr
Debug.Print(sMyNewArray(0)(0))
```

throws an error while

```
Dim sMyNewArray As Array() = ComboBox.Items.Item(3).Arr
Debug.Print(UBound(sMyNewArray(UBound(sMyNewArray))))
```

does not and prints the last item's last row's ubound

Can anyone figure out what is it I'm missing or tell me a better way to do this? I'm pretty sure there is one..

Comment: Multidimensional or jagged arrays have their place but they are often used when there are better alternatives.  What exactly does the data represent? If we know that, we can recommend a better alternative if there is one.

Comment: i have a feeling you are running into a misunderstanding of how references are handled in vb.net. I'd follow this article, and instead of using the plain Array class, use the built in array declaration syntax. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/parameter-arrays

Comment: This is pretty much the text I have to store in a single combobox item. Every item can have different amount of "Systems" with different data.

Comment: Wow.. I mean in the text file there is "Systemx=" in the beginning of each line and then the data separated with ; and the amount of lines or systems is unknown. And I need to get the selected item's 2-dim array's data into another array of same size.

Comment: Simpler data example:

Comment: `System0=a;b;c;d;e;f 
System1=A;B;C;D;E;F;G 
System2=H;R;x;E;S;g;u;x 
System3=y;n;d;e;F;T 
System4=I;dont;get;it`

Comment: In VB.NET you can also use single-line [Auto-Implemented Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/auto-implemented-properties): `Public Property Arr As Array()` without any `Get` or `Set` implementation.

Comment: Nice! I will use that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think the problem is in this section:

```
Dim sMyArray as Array()

For i As Integer = 0 to 3
    sMyArray = Nothing   ' resetting the array before refilling it
```

Arrays are technically reference types, but like strings, there's some extra compiler magic to make them feel at times more like value types, and I have a sense in this case the actual `sMyArray` reference was used (perhaps because of a `ParamArrays` optimzation), such that setting it to `Nothing` broke things. The more idiomatic way to write this code for .Net it like this:

```
For i As Integer = 0 to 3
    Dim sMyArray as Array()
```

.Net has a much more sophisticated garbage collector than was available for VB6. We don't often set variables to `Nothing` any more, but instead just re-assign them or let them fall out of scope. In fact, setting a variable to `Nothing` can in rare cases be actively harmful. Moreover, we want to see the `Dim` keyword inside the loop, so you're working with a *different variable* on each iteration, with the smallest possible scope.

While I'm here, in .Net we pretty much *never* use the base `Array` type. Instead of this:

```
Private sArr As Array()
```

You pretty much **always** do this:

```
Private arr As String()()
```

or this, for true two-dimensional (non-jagged) arrays:

```
Private arr As String(,)
```

or, best of all, this:

```
Private arr As New List(Of String())
```

Since VB.Net has more collection types than just array.

Also, I don't have the link handy, but Microsoft's coding guidelines now explicitly ask you **not** to use hungarian warts for variable and class names (so `sArr` can just be `arr`). This is a change from the VB6 era because of changes to the language where the type is more likely to be implicit with the variable and improvements to the tooling, where the prefixes usually no longer add much utility and have been shown to hurt readability.

Comment: Yes it works now! Using String()() instead of Array() was the key and also taking the ParamArray out. I was using array() because I didn't know that each 2nd dimension array can be individually sized. Well of course you can. It's called progress. If I remember correctly you could not do this in VB6 at least there were no easy way doing this. I guess this is what the jagged array means? Many thanks, Joel!

Comment: If this answer helped, you should accept it so other readers know it's the correct/usefull one and the author gets credit. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure why you have a 2 dimensional array, but here is a small sample NOT using the Array type. It uses just plain strings and string arrays. Let me know if this helps. This splits a few strings, then reads out the results after populating.

```
Public Class Form1



    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim sMyArray()() As String

        Dim line1 As String = "a;b;c;d 1;2;3;4;5"
        Dim line2 As String = "z;x;y;w 99;65;32;21;18"

        sMyArray = ParseString(line1)
        cboBox1.Items.Add(New MyItem("System0", sMyArray))

        sMyArray = ParseString(line2)
        cboBox1.Items.Add(New MyItem("System1", sMyArray))

        For i As Integer = 0 To cboBox1.Items.Count - 1

            For j As Integer = 0 To UBound(cboBox1.Items(i).arr)
                For k As Integer = 0 To UBound(cboBox1.Items(i).arr(j))
                    Debug.Write(cboBox1.Items(i).arr(j)(k) & " ")
                Next

            Next
            Debug.WriteLine("")
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Function ParseString(s As String) As String()()
        Dim rows As String() = s.Split(" ")
        Dim matrix As String()() = New String(rows.Length - 1)() {}

        For i As Integer = 0 To rows.Length - 1
            matrix(i) = rows(i).Split(";")
        Next

        Return matrix

    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyItem

    Private sName As String
    Private sArr As String()()


    Public Sub New(ByVal Name As String, ByVal ParamArray Arr As String()())
        sName = Name
        sArr = Arr
    End Sub

    Public Property Arr() As String()()
        Get
            Return sArr
        End Get

        Set(ByVal sValue As String()())
            sArr = sValue
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return sName
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort Jeremy. But the t1 and t2 has to be in the same combobox item. And there could be random number of tx's in every combobox item. For example item 0 may have t1...t8 and item 1 t1...t23 and so on, depending on the amount of lines in the text file. So that's why 2-dimensional.

Comment: I'll kind of use the combobox to select which file's lines are used.

Comment: modified to work with 2 dimensional array and native string types

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. This wasn't quite the way I needed since I don't want to use a parser or could not change the format of the files. But using String()() and taking ParamArray out solved it. Thanks!

Comment: great. it was meant to demonstrate the concept anyways as I couldn't see your actual code.